# Component Height - Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, thermal

I'm using Altium Designer version 14.2. I am making a thermal analysis. The  Analyze program expects a ODB++ format input from me. When I convert my PCB to ODB++, I can't see any height information about my PCB component on analysis program. When I am searching to fix this problem, I found some information. When I look at my pcb library, I saw there is no height information on my component, but there is a 3D CAD file associated. But there is overall height information. How can I convert overall height to height? Or is there any solution for this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you configured the ODB++ Setup window to add 3D body layers? Are you still having this issue then? https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/workspacemanager-dlg-odbsetup-formodb-setup-ad

Comment: I think that the 'Height' field you show in the PCB Library Component window is an old default field that has no connection to 3d models.  It's just a text field that the most-basic clearance rules can use when there's no 3d information available.  One could enter the max height in this text field during component creation, for record-keeping, and basic clearance-rules checking.

Comment: @Cisco25 Hi, I do not have any 3D body layers on my PCB. How can ı get these layers?

Comment: @AlicanOzpay It has been a long time I haven't used Altium, have you fetched for help on their forums? Also why are you using such an old version?